# I want to make an <a> tag to switch my 4 iframes content at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a website for my school that contains 4 iframes(Semester1, Semester 2, Semester 3, Semester 4).
I want to add a button that contains 13 numbers (from 1 to 13) that represents the number of groups in my school,
and when the user chose a number the iframes changes its containt according to the group selected
can you please tell me how to make this code in html/css/js ?
here is a photo that can make you understand my goal better:[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did you encounter a problem? StackOverlfow is a commuity to help each other with problems we encounter, not a way to have somebody do your work for you. Please provide [a minimal, reproduible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: i literally dont know what to do so i want to know?

Comment: what im trying is:
creating a parent a tag that contains 4 child a tags, each one deals with an iframe
the code something like this: 
<a>father tag
            <a href="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=1lyEGBCoXoACwwu8DOYbkUwHl1rrO_9rh" target="g11">child tag1</a>
            <a href="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=1p3QNvVxo10Z-t-TVBm5w3_GP4RnWHgRB" target="g12">chilg tag2</a>
        </a>
        <iframe name="g11" width="200px" height="300px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <iframe name="g12" width="300px" height="500px" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: but its not working

Comment: Well, tbh: learn Javascript prgramming first. There's courses, online tutorials, books, or whatever you prefer. It's unlikely somebody will just do all the coding for you.

Comment: ok i will do so, thanks